# Creating a google sheets sumif with case-insensitive criteria

Tags: google-sheets, case-insensitive, sumifs

I am trying to create a `SUMIF` with a case-insensitive criteria (.ie contains, but not necessarily match).

Currently testing for a date range and one criteria. I would like to add one more criteria that checks for text contained in a cell in column `'Time Entry'!$J$2:$J$5993`.

```
SUMIFS('Time Entry'!$G$2:$G$5993,'Time Entry'!$K$2:$K$5993,$A6,'Time Entry'!$D$2:$D$5993,">=" & $A$2,'Time Entry'!$D$2:$D$5993,"<=" & $B$2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a dummy copy of your sheet?

Comment: use the `search` formula as the criterion

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF` is already case insensitive, if you want to match something "contains, but not necessarily match" you can use wildcards.

- `?` to match any single character
- `*` to match any sequence of characters

So this will match any cell that contains "christmas" (or "Christmas" or "CHristmas" etc.)

```
=SUMIF(A1:A99,"*christmas*",B1:B99)
```

If you want to get your search value itself from a cell you can write it like this (if your value was in C1):

```
=SUMIF(A1:A99,"*"&C1&"*",B1:B99)
```

If your are looking for an actual question mark or asterisk, escape it with the tilde like this: `~?` or `~*`.

*(late answer and not sure if the OP was looking for this but maybe conventient for future visitors)*